# Read Sitecore Item ID on user control on html tag

Tags: sitecore-api

I created an Accordion component in Sitecore(web-forms) and it's working fine. But if I add multiple accordions on the same page it's opening up the first accordion even though if I click on the second one.

To resolve this I need to pass some unique ID, so I thought of passing sitecore item ID to resolve this but so far no luck.

Here's my code: (I am using **asp:Repeater**)

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ItemID>" >Heading</a>
```

Is there any way to pass the Sitecore item ID ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get Sitecore Item Id on user control using below code

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<%#((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem).ID.ToShortID()%>" >
```

it will provide you item id on anchor tag.

Comment: Thank you Rishiraj, that worked perfectly.